# ifstream getline does not find delim

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

If the ifstream::getline call does not find the delimeter I know it sets failbit but does it also clear out the buffer or does it leave the buffer intact and just set the fail bit to let you know?

Comment: It leaves the buffer intact, containting what was extracted before `failbit` was set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about the different states of an input stream (and rightly so, they *are* confusing):

C++ Standard, table 124

> - `badbit` indicates a loss of integrity in an input or output sequence (such as an irrecoverable read error from a file);
> - `eofbit` indicates that an input operation reached the end of an input sequence;
> - `failbit` indicates that an input operation failed to read the expected characters, or
>     that an output operation failed to generate the desired characters.

That is, `failbit` is set when `basic_istream::getline(char_type* s, std::streamsize count, char_type delim)` extracts `count-1` characters without finding the delimiter (`-1` for the terminating `\0` stored). This does not indicate the stream is `bad`, but it rather indicates that `getline` has failed to find the delimiter.

Description of `basic_istream::getline` in the C++ Standard:
[istream.unformatted]/18

> - Effects: [...] After constructing a sentry object [= preparation for input and error checks], extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of an array whose first element is designated by `s`. **Characters are extracted and stored until one of the following occurs**:
>
>   1. end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls `setstate(eofbit)`);
>   2. `traits::eq(c, delim)` [= delimiter found] for the next available input character `c` (in which case the input character is extracted but not stored);
>   3. `n` is less than one or `n - 1` characters are stored (in which case the function calls `setstate(failbit)`).
>        [...]
> - These conditions are tested in the order shown.
> - If the function extracts no characters, it calls `setstate(failbit)` [...]
> - In any case, if `n` is greater than zero, it then stores a null character [...] into the next successive location of the array.

[emphasis and omissions mine]

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

> Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first
>   constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to true). Then (if
>   good), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object
>   as if calling its member functions sbumpc or sgetc, and finally
>   destroys the sentry object before returning.

It seems that the buffer is filled until there is a problem. (See DyP's comments)

Comment: I'm tryint to get more information on this behavior but from what I understand I'd say it leaves it intact.

Comment: I don't think so?? The sentry object is to check whether the stream is good or not; `getline` extracts **until** some condition like end-of-file occurs; see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) or Standard [istream.unformatted]/18, "Characters are extracted and stored until one of the following occurs:"

Comment: The `badbit` (and with it, the `basic_ios::bad` function) does not indicate an end-of-file (-> `eofbit`).